# How to move all existing containers on another instance before auto scale in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-ecs

I am using AWS ECS in combination with EC2 instances.

Right now I am setting up Auto Scaling. How can I make sure that when, an EC2 instance gets terminated, all ECS tasks get migrated before the machine gets terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it is not automatically possible to achieve this. The best approach would be to have atleast 2 tasks running of each service, spread on different instances via a [placement constraint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html).

Manually (or scripted) it is possible:

If you want to replace an instance attached to an ECS cluster, you can simply [drain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-instance-draining.html) the instance. This will do the following

1. Start a new task of each running service on another instance in the cluster
2. Wait until the recently started task is 'steady'
3. shutdown the old task

To drain an instance using the AWS CLI, do the following:

1. Open the Amazon ECS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Clusters and select the cluster.
3. Choose ECS Instances and select the check box for the container
   instances.
4. Choose Actions, Drain instances.
5. After the instances are processed, choose Done.

This can also be done via the [command line](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-container-instances-state.html).

To do it automatically, you will need to add a [lifecycle hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html#adding-lifecycle-hooks) on termination.

Call the AWS CLI from the termination lifecycle hook to drain the instance, wait a fixed amount of time and then continue terminating the instance.

Comment: Thank you. Is there way to make this task automated before EC2 instance gets terminated with AWS Auto Scaling?

Comment: yes, you could add Lifecycle hooks. Added it to my anser